# How to add module to nginx on CentOS 6

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, nginx, upload

I have nginx 1.4.4 as reverse proxy and apache as backend. My question is - how to add modules to nginx?

I need this module http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule

checked `nginx -V` i don't have this module

I read that  i need to recompile nginx with a new module. How to do that? How to save old nginx config files so i won't mess up my webserver?

Comment: It's really not a great idea to do this, especially if you're someone who doesn't already know how to do it. Compiling your own stuff comes with significant potential maintenance and security downfalls. If you need upload progress, consider something like Plupload to do it client-side.

Comment: Already did it and it wasn't so hard, but now i learned how to compile from source or recompile RPM.

Comment: It's not so hard to compile. What's often hard is keeping up on patches and ensuring the custom process is well documented.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ceejayoz in his comment above that you're taking a big step if you move off RPM and start compiling on your own. Migrating might be a really big pain in the butt. Once you do it, though, you have much more freedom in the future. If you think you might use other modules in the future, then it might be the right step.

See this question for help migrating off RPM builds on Centos 6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568784/can-this-package-be-recompiled

Comment: I have successfully recompiled SRPM wasn't that hard. Thanks